# How to replace a backslash CR LF with a <br> with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've tried many combinations of attempting to replace a "\ cr lf" with an html "br" tag after "foo".

My input file (tempA.txt) looks like this (there is a cr lf at the end of line 1 after the slash):

```
foo\
bar
```

I'm using a powershell command (within a bat file) like this:

```
type c:\temp\tempA.txt
powershell -Command "(gc c:\temp\tempA.txt) -replace '\\`r`n', '<br>' | Out-File c:\temp\tempB.txt"
type c:\temp\tempB.txt
```

My output file (tempB.txt) isn't changing.  I want the output file to contain

```
foo<br>bar
```

How do you replace the "\ cr lf" with a simple html "br" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-Content will split your file into an array of lines. Based on this, you can just replace `\` with `<br>` and join the lines together.

```
(gc c:\temp\tempA.txt) -replace '\\', '<br>' -join '' | Out-File c:\temp\tempB.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your first `-replace` operator arg to use a double quoted string:

```
... -replace "\\`r`n", '<br>'
```

A single quoted string in PowerShell is a literal string so the backtick doesn't work to escape characters.